# In the book, "Who Goes There" by John W. Campbell, how do they know that Gary and Copper are monsters?

Tags: who-goes-there, john-w-campbell-jr

The book explains the tests they take with the blood to identify who is a monster, but then the tests don't work.  Somehow they all think for certain that either Garry or Copper are monsters, but how do they know?

Answer (score 2):

The blood test is supposed to work by triggering an immune response in one of the dogs.  The idea was to inject it with small quantities of human tissue, so that the dog would develop antibodies to the human tissue.  (This is the normal way that the adaptive immune system in mammals gains immunity to pathogens that it is exposed to.)  Once the dog’s immune system had been sensitized, its blood would rapidly react if it were exposed to the same (human) tissue again.  (That’s why we can fight off many viruses that we have had before, like chicken pox or measles, and it’s how vaccines work—by sensitizing the immune system to a dangerous virus that we might be exposed to in the future.)

So whatever the dog was exposed to, it would develop an immune response to, which could later be measured.  The idea was then to look for a rapid immune response by the dog’s blood to tissue taken from each person in camp.  If the blood reacted, it would mean that the blood was human, because it contained the same kinds of foreign proteins that the dog had already been exposed to.  Copper explains it thus:

> ”If I had a rabbit that had been injected with human blood ­ a poison to rabbits, of course, as is the blood of any animal save that of another rabbit, and the injections continued in increasing doses for some time, the rabbit would be human-immune.  If a small quantity of its blood were drawn off, allowed to separate in a test­-tube, and to the clear serum, a bit of human blood were added, there would be a visible reaction, proving the blood was human.  If cow, or dog blood were added, or any protein material other than that one thing, human blood, no reaction would take place.  That would prove definitely.”

However, when it came time to do the test, it was found that the dog had already been exposed to both human and Thing tissue.  It had acquired immunity to both of them already.  The only way that could have happened would be if the dog had been exposed to both human blood and monster blood.  Again, Copper:

> "Garry, tissue from the monster ­ precipitates too.  It proves nothing.  Nothing but—but the dog was monster-immune too.  That one of the two contributing blood—one of us two, you and I, Garry—one of us is a monster.”

That means that, when they started dosing the dog, at least one of Garry and Copper was human; but by the time they were finished, at least one of them was Thing.  The likeliest explanation is that one of them was assimilated the entire time.*

It is eventually revealed, in quite memorable fashion, that Garry is the alien.

> Garry spoke in a low, bitter voice. “Connant was one of the finest men we had here, and five minutes ago I'd have sworn he was a man. Those damnable things are more than imitation.”  Garry shuddered and sat back in his bunk.
>
> And thirty seconds later, Garry's blood shrank from the hot platinum wire, and struggled to escape the tube, struggled as frantically as a suddenly feral, red­-eyed, dissolving imitation of Garry struggled to dodge the snake­-tongue weapon Barclay advanced at him, white faced and sweating. The Thing in the test­-tube screamed with a tiny, tinny voice as McReady dropped it into the glowing coal of the galley stove.

*Of course, none of this reasoning is watertight (and one of the recurring themes of the story is actually that the humans make all kinds of mistakes in dealing with the Thing).  With an alien creature as adaptable as the Thing, the characters can't really know what kind of proteins the creature produces at a microscopic level, whether they should resemble human proteins or not.  However, this is the reasoning that the characters in the story—in particular, Dr. Copper—rely on; and the fact that Garry does turn out the be an alien suggests that Copper's reasoning may well have been correct.

Comment: I am being pedantic, but that does not prove much. It could be that when the Thing is imitating a human, it also produced human blood proteins, or at least proteins that are similar enough to trigger an immune response. This is the cross-reactivity that some have hypothesized to occur between COVID-19 and other coronaviruses. 
Given the accuracy of the Thing's imitation (memories?) that seems more than plausible. Besides the problem of non-specific antibody binding.

Comment: @Adamant That's all perfectly correct.  I should add a note that this reasoning is not necessarily correct; however, that is the reasoning that the characters in the story (particularly Copper) use.

Comment: Also, it seems like they mixed both their blood in the original test? Of course that was suboptimal, because it would not show which one was a Thing if indeed one of them was. If they had exposed it to one person's blood first, then a later positive reaction with the Thing material would suggest that person was the Thing. A lack of any reaction would suggest the other person by process of elimination. In fact, it would have been infinitely smarter to expose the dog to the Thing material first, then test its blood against both people separately! Success = Thing, failure = human.

Comment: @Adamant Have you read the story?  One of the recurring themes is that the humans make lots of mistakes in their fight against the Thing, and it almost costs them (and the whole human race) dearly.

Comment: Yes, I have read it. The second bit is certainly forgiveable in a stressful situation but the first bit is not an error that almost any scientist trained in a field would make.

Comment: @Adamant Well, Campbell was not a scientist, and he was often bad at understanding real science and thinking like a scientist.  (He was taken in by Dianetics for a while, after all.)  Even in "Who Goes There," he cites Rhine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Banks_Rhine) as having demonstrated telepathy, when almost no scientists outside Rhine's lab was convinced by his Rhine's results.

Comment: @Adamant On the other hand, Campbell's loose understanding of scientific principles was occasionally prescient.  I have a talk I give to professional physicists, pointing out that his story "Cloak of Aesir" contains the first description of a quantum anomaly.  In detail, it's nothing like the real quantum anomalies discovered decades later, but the key idea is there.

Comment: @Buzz "Campbell was not a scientist"? Campbell earned a bachelor's degree in Physics. I don't believe he ever used it to make a steady living (by working in a physics lab, for instance), but he did have the training. Isn't that enough to let us call him a scientist?

Comment: @Adamant About the possibility of a Thing in human shape producing "human blood proteins," I'm reminded of one moment in the story that gave me a chill. Some of the men have just reported electrocuting the "cows" which turned out to be Things. The cook (I think) yells, "I just milked them this morning!" When the men check out the remaining milk in the kitchen, it doesn't react violently to a dose of electricity. Someone says (roughly): "Either the cows were only recently replaced by Things, or else perfect copies of cows give perfectly good milk." (continued)

Comment: @Adamant But for a moment there, after the cook made the very logical leap to the idea that the milk might be extremely dangerous, I'd been imagining all the previously-human characters walking around with miniature Thing fluids sloshing around inside their stomachs, gradually absorbing and converting more and more of the human host's biomass . . . all because the men liked to have milk with their morning oatmeal, or whatever they'd eaten for breakfast.

Comment: @Lorendiac It always seemed to me that the Kinner Thing missed an opportunity to infect the whole group with the milk.  But maybe that wasn't possible after all; if there is one thing that's clear about the Thing's biology, it's that we don't understand it.

Comment: @Lorendiac This may sound snide and/or elitist, but I don't think of just anybody with an undergraduate degree in the sciences as a "scientist."  Certainly, I would never call Campbell a "physicist"; besides not being a researcher, his knowledge of the field was clearly far too patchy.